# Number of ways to derive the number 14 using a recursive definition of EVEN numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I have the following recursive definition for the construction of EVEN Numbers-

```
[RULE 1]: 2 is an EVEN number.

[RULE 2]: If x is an EVEN number and y is an EVEN number, then x+y is also an EVEN number.
```

In how many ways can the number 14 be derived using the above definition? For example, one way to derive 14 is

```
2 is in EVEN,
 2+2 = 4 is in EVEN,
 4 + 4 = 8 is in EVEN, 
8 + 4 = 12 is in EVEN 
and finally 12 + 2 = 14 is in EVEN.
```

I tried by trial-and-error and I could get a answer (9 ways) for this problem but

(1) I am not sure if my answer is correct

(2) I failed to find a general pattern i.e given a EVEN number n, does there exist a function f(n) which will give me the number of ways to derive n?

Comment: Suppose I prove that 6 and 8 are even.  Then I could say either "14 = 6+8" or "14 = 8+6".  Are those considered the same proof, or different proofs?

Comment: What do you consider different?  Is 2+2=4,4+2=6,6+2=8 different from 2+2=4,4+2=6,4+4=8?

Comment: If you posted the 9 ways that you found, it would help us understand the unclear parts of your question.

Comment: The part that is unclear to me is the following - If for a given integer n I have f(n) ways to derive the integer using the above definition, then,  how can I use it to know the number of ways to derive n+1, that is, how f(n+1) can be expressed in terms of f(n)?

Comment: You're not answering either MJD's or Ross Millikan's questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(n)$: Number of ways the integer $n$ can be derived from the above definition.

For every even number $n$ we must consider the following partitions recursively:

$$
n = (n-2) + 2\\
n = (n-4) + 4\\
n = (n-6) + 6\\
\cdots\\
n = s + t
$$

where $s$ and $t$ are defined as follows:

$$
(s, t) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  (\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{2})  & \mbox{if } \frac{n}{2}~is~even \\
  (ceil(\frac{n}{2}), floor(\frac{n}{2})) & otherwise
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

They are defined in this way because I presume that the order of the numbers in the each partition doesn't matter. If the order is important to you, continue partitions to $n = 2 + (n-2)$ instead.

But this is the top level of our recursion. After using each partition we must continue partitioning the parts in the same way. So we can define the $f(n)$:

$$
f(n) =\Sigma_{i=1}^{t/2}f(n-2i) + f(2i)\\
f(2) = 1
$$

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you're proving the same facts multiple times.

Comment: What same facts?